# How can I transform it in a list of tuples key-value again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook, tuples

I want to transform it:

```
[('user1', 10),('user2',2),('user2',24),('user1',10),('user3',15),('user3',8)]
```

to it:

```
[('user2', 0.52), ('user3', 0.46), ('user1', 0.4)]
```

I need to add the values, grouping by user, apply the rate of 2% and sort by descendant value.

I've completed the solution with libs, but i want to complete just with conditionals. I'm using the jupyter notebook.

```
e = [('user1', 10),('user2',2),('user2',24),('user1',10),('user3',15),('user3',8)]
type(e)
users = ["user1","user2","user3"]
for u in users:
    value = 0
    for t in e:
        user = t[0]
        if user == u:
            value = value + t[1]
    finalValue = value* 0.02
```

I've tried a lot of times to transform the `"finalValue"` but I recived the message

> "'float' object is not iterable".

Comment: I get no error when I run your code but I do have `finalValue` of 0.46 which happens because you overwrite this every loop (of users) and it ends up just doing this for the last `user3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)

data = [('user1', 10),('user2',2),('user2',24),('user1',10),('user3',15),('user3',8)]
for k, v in data:
    result[k] += v

result = {k: v*0.02 for k, v in result.items()}
#or result = [(k, v*0.02) for k, v in result.items()]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'user2': 0.52, 'user3': 0.46, 'user1': 0.4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code just needs a little modification to make it do what you want:

```
e = [('user1', 10),('user2',2),('user2',24),('user1',10),('user3',15),('user3',8)]
type(e)
users = ["user1","user2","user3"]
f = []     # initialize list for storing final values
for u in users:
    value = 0
    for t in e:
        user = t[0]
        if user == u:
            value = value + t[1]
    finalValue = value* 0.02
    f.append((u, finalValue))  # add final value to list
```

With that, I get an `f` of:

```
[('user1', 0.4), ('user2', 0.52), ('user3', 0.46)]
```

Comment: How to sort by the float number ?

Comment: `f.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. First you get the set of unique users, then sum all the instances where that unique user occurs. Then use a dict-comprehension to get the result :

```
l = [('user1', 10),('user2',2),('user2',24),('user1',10),('user3',15),('user3',8)]
uniq_user = set(m[0] for m in l)
# uniq_user = {'user1', 'user2', 'user2'}

l2 = [(i, sum(n[1] for n in l if n[0]==i)) for i in uniq_user] 
# l2 = [('user3', 23), ('user1', 20), ('user2', 26)]

outp = {i1 : i2*0.02 for i1,i2 in l2}
```

**Output** :

```
{'user3': 0.46, 'user1': 0.4, 'user2': 0.52}
```